# Django proxy model is visible on admin site but not showing up in permissions section of the production admin site

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

- Locally I can see the proxy model on the admin site and permissions are visible in the permission section and can be assigned to different users.
- In production I can see the proxy model on the admin site but permissions are not visible in the permission section and therefore cannot be assigned to different users.

I'm expecting to see something like :

```
apps|details|can add
apps|details|can delete
apps|details|can update
apps|details|can view
```

in the permissions section. For other models the permissions are visible.

Versions:

```
djangorestframework --> 3.12.2
python --> 3.8
```

Dir:

```
+Apps - profile - models.py
                - admin.py
      - details - models.py
                - admin.py
```

profile/models.py

```
class Profile:
  # Model Details
```

details/models.py

```
from profile.models import Profile

class ProxyProfile(Profile):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        app_label = 'details'
        verbose_name = 'ProxyProfile'
        verbose_name_plural = 'ProxyProfiles'
```

details/admin.py

```
from models import ProxyProfile

class ProxyProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  # Admin Model Details

admin.site.register(ProxyProfile, ProxyProfileAdmin)
```

Comment: Have all migrations been run on the production site? See also https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default/#default-permissions for how these objects are created.

Comment: I ran migrate on production site and it picked the permissions. Thank you Nick. 

But then the questions is, for some previous changes the admin site would pick the changes on startup. Even for this one, the model was there which implied the migration file was loaded and the migration ran on start up, so why didn't the permissions pick ?

Comment: Not sure. Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/0dd29209091280ccf34e07c9468746c396b7778e/django/contrib/auth/apps.py#L19), the django.contrib.auth app is responsible for installing a post_migrate signal which creates permissions after each migration. Perhaps migrations were interrupted before permissions were created, or the django.contrib.auth app wasn't loaded when you last ran migrations?

Comment: I think django.contrib.auth will definitely load on system restart since it is a default app so probably it was a migration interruption.